# SublimeText 3: Missing Package Control

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimelinter

I'm looking to download the sublimeLinter package for SublimeText 3. Following the download instructions [here](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) I open the command palette on my Mac (CMD + Shift + P) and type install...no results. The desired Package Control: Install Package title does not exist on my system.

I'm usingSublimeText build 3114. It downloaded soundlessly, and works well. But where is my Package Control? This is missing, and comes directly from documentation.

Comment: PackageControl is itself a plugin. https://packagecontrol.io/installation

Comment: Thanks tkausl, I probably could have read more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Package Control is itself a plugin. See [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

Answer (score 1):

To `Install Packages` first you have to setup the `package control` for you `sublime text`

To do That just follow the below official installation page

https://packagecontrol.io/installation

and follow the instruction. you can choose either `simple` or `manual` method of installation.

when installation complete restart your `sublime text` and install any packages you need.